# Unable to consume ServiceNow API to create incident (ticket) in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

https://xxxx.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/incident while we're consuming this API in postman we're getting

> {
>       "error": {
>           "message": "User Not Authenticated",
>           "detail": "Required to provide Auth information"
>       },
>       "status": "failure"
>   }

Here we are given basic authentication and the JSON input like

```
{
"short_description":"Creating incident through Request",
"assignment_group":"287ebd7da9fe198100f92cc8d1d2154e",
"urgency":"3",
"impact":"3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It basically says you are not authenticated, it either means you didnt provide correct credentials or you forgot to provide basic-auth header while querying through postman

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is pretty clear about what the problem is... you're not authenticated. You'll need to authenticate in order to utilize the API. Unless you have a complex authentication scheme going, you can probably use Basic Authentication in PostMan and use the credentials for an account which you know has access to the resource you're trying to access.

Comment: I am providing the credentials for which I got the access. But Here I am getting two sets of credentials. one is to login into ServiceNow account and another one is for accessing the instance. So which credentials we need to use to access the REST API for creating incident(ticket) in ServiceNow

Comment: "one is to login into ServiceNow account and another one is for accessing the instance."
This doesn't make sense. You mean one is a webservices account? You can do REST using any account with access to the resource you're trying to access.